# mongoose - storing an array of ids in mongoDB at storage time, but getting entire objects back at runtime?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to setup a mongoose model of what I want in my mongodb instance.

here is the code I have for a user type so far.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema(
{
    username: String,
    userType: int,
    tagline: String,
    friends: <Not sure what to do here>
}));
```

Essentially, I want to only store the ids of other users in here at insert time etc, but when I query to GET this user, I want to actually get the json that would have the various users I want to get back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose provides a mechanism for referencing other collections and populating them. I'm making the assumption the _ids in friends are other Users so you can define your schema as

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema(
{
    username: String,
    userType: int,
    tagline: String,
    friends: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
}));
```

And then you can use the built in `populate` method in mongoose to retrieve the actual documents and not just the _ids

```
User
.findOne({ username: username })
.populate('friends')
.exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(user.friends);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I need to use [Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). So you define your fields as `ref`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    username: String,
    userType: int,
    tagline: String,
    friends:[{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
}));
```

And could fetch your friends as array of objects via `.populate` method:

```
User.findById(id)
   .populate('friends')
   .exec(function (err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;

       // user.friends is array of users
       console.log(user.friends)
   })
```

Comment: I wish I could have two best answers, you are both right! Thanks!